# How to Reference TextBox in One UserControl from Another UserControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have two UserControls on a MasterPage. DataEntryUC contains several TextBoxes and DropDownList. NavSaveUC contains navigation buttons. When the user clicks on a navigation button, I will be saving the data entered into DataEntryUC from the NavSaveUC UserControl.

I have a couple of tables in my DB that contain stored procedure names, control names, control types, SqlDbTypes, etc.... that correlate with DataEntryUC.

How do I reference a text box that is on DataEntryUC from NavSaveUC?

I have been working on the following code from NavSaveUC with no luck.

```
Dim MyControlName = "txtFirstName"
Dim MyControlType = "TextBox"
Dim MyStringValue as String
Dim tmpTxtControl as TextBox
Dim tmpDdlControl as DropDownList

Select Case MyControlType
    Case "TextBox"
        tmpTxtControl = CType(Page.FindControl(MyControlName, TextBox)
        MyStringValue = tmpTxtControl.Text                  
    Case "DropDownList"
        tmpDdlControl = CType(Page.FindControl(MyControlName, DropDownList)
        MyStringValue = tmpDdlControl.SelectedValue
End Select
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the textbox as a property of the user control and access it that way. This type of dependency is not a best practice though.

Comment: Yes, Exposing that control as property is easy&best approach. Here is an example for that..http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155

Comment: When following the example shown, they are referencing the control in the source code for the page. (<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/ControlB.ascx" %>)  I will be using this button navigation control against multiple userControls. I would have to reference all user controls that will be used in conjunction with my NaveSaveUC correct?

Comment: Just reference the relevant user controls on the page that the button resides on. Also, user controls have to be manually deployed if they are used somewhere else.

Comment: I have multiple user controls on each aspx page. For instance... the Birth.aspx page is using a MasterPage. Birth.aspx also contains the following UserControls: DataEntryUC_1.ascx, DataEntryUC_2.ascx, DataEntryUC_3.ascx and NavSaveUC.ascx. There will be multiple combinations of UserControls on each .aspx page. I can't add the relevant controls with NavSaveUC because of this can I?

Comment: Just add whichever ones you're using. You can have as many as you need.

Comment: Ok. I finally got this to work by following the example. I had problems with Page.FindControl. I kept receiving Nothing. After playing around with it, I changed it to Parent.FindControl. This fixed my error.  Thanks you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

If the one user control is embedded inside the other user control, then simply expose it as a property of the control. If, however, both user controls separately exist on the same page, the controls should not interact directly with each other to avoid a dependency between the controls.

Instead, you should use the page as an intermediary between the two controls. For instance, NavSaveUC can raise an event with data in it's event argument when an action is performed. The page can handle the event from NavSaveUC. If DataEntryUC exposes the text box or text box's text property as a public property, the page's event handler can get data from NavSaveUC's event argument and place it in DataEntryUC's text box.